# Number of users in a ranking MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

To get the ranking of the user 3 I am using this query (It works fine):

```
$sql = "SELECT 
score,
FIND_IN_SET(score, 
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score 
ORDER BY score DESC)
FROM results)
) AS rank
FROM results
WHERE user_id = 3
";
```

Table structure:

**user_id - score**

Now I want to give the user 3 some points. My formule is:

Number of score (Or users) - rank + 1.

So if I have 20 users (Or score) and the ranking of the user 3 is 10, so the points will be:

**20 - 10 + 1 = 11** points.

**PS**: users (Or score) = some users have more than one score.

How can I get the number of score (Or users) using this mysql query?

**SQL FIDDLE**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff4505/4

Comment: @YLS: the table structure is: user_id - score

Comment: some users have more than one score.  - eh?

Comment: I don't understand this statement. A proper example may help.

Comment: add "sample data" and "expected result" to this question, mystery surrounds your explanation that would be clarified when we see data (in text form please, not an image, or set up a http://sqlfiddle.com )

Comment: @Strawberry I don't have another example. I use this example.

In the competition of 100 meter I have the time of 20 athletes. I want to return the number of the athletes. In this example is 20. Forget about the points. Just the number of the athletes. 
The problem is here: WHERE user_id = 3 because when I use COUNT(*) AS totalScore I get only the number of the user_id 3 (Offcourse)

Comment: If you can't help us, we can't help you.

Comment: I just added a fiddle. See my update post please. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this ... I hope it help you ...

```
SELECT user_id,@all_user := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `results`) as all_count,((@all_user-score)+1) as rank FROM `results` WHERE user_id = 3
```

Comment: Thanks YLS:) You did not only solve my problem, byt I learned something new:)

Answer (score 1):

Improved Answer

```
$sql = "SELECT @all_user := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `results`) 
        as all_count,((@all_user-score)+1) as rank FROM `results` WHERE user_id = 3";
```